# error on table while adding to combobox c#

Tags: c#, wpf, ado.net

> Error 1 The name 'tblstudent' does not exist in the current context

```
void FillNationality()
{
    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
    connection.ConnectionString = "Integrated Security=true; Initial Catalog = student; Data Source = Yudish-PC";
    connection.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter d = new SqlDataAdapter("select country from tbl_nationality", connection);
    DataSet dt = new DataSet();
d.Fill(dt);
    cmbnationality.DataSource = dt.Tables[0]; /// assign the first table of dataset
    cmbnationality.DisplayMember = "country";  /// assign the column country to be displayed
    cmbnationality.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", tblstudent, "nationality_id");                                          

    connection.Close();
}
```

Comment: What is this? C# or Java? You know that they're not the same and so your use of both tags will only serve to confuse.

Comment: You're trying to use a variable called `tblstudent`.  Where do you declare that variable?  The compiler seems to think that you don't.

Comment: it is c#
and tblstudent is the table name from my database.

Comment: @YudishNundun: You're not using it as a table name, though.  You're using it as a C# variable, where it doesn't exist.  You're not even using it in your SQL query, so it's really unclear what you're even trying to do in that last line before closing the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the code

```
cmbnationality.DataBindings.Add("SelectedValue", tblstudent, "nationality_id");
```

tblstudent is not defined, in the current scope of the method